# creating a small lottery application, java

Tags: java

I'm a java noob and have been looking all over for some help with how to create this lottery application. I read some examples on this site but some of the code was a bit too advanced for me to actually implement(I'm not sure how O(n) works?) so I thought I'd asked my question here while I keep looking for the answers.

I need to create a really simple application that generates 3 random numbers and compares them with 3 user guesses. The numbers are all single digit but they can be repeating. For example the actual numbers might be 1, 1, 1 and the user may have guessed 1, 2, 3 but the prize money would only match the 1 the user guessed with any 1 in the actual number for a single match.

I just need to compare 2 arrays I guess and account for repeating digits. I tried creating nested if statements but there's 20 or so premutations and it gets out of hand really fast. What would a pro do?

Thanks for any help

Comment: O(n) is big O notation: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Big_O_notation

Comment: Could we see some more examples of winning guesses, and losing guesses?

Comment: Yeah, I'm a little stumped because there is alot of potential winnings to be earned. A single match is any one number that matches between the 2 groups; order does not matter (ex 112, 233; or 187, 843)
a twomatch is the same idea with 2 numbers matching; order does not matter(ex 234, 364; or 333, 393) and a threematch is the same with 3 matching numbers (ex 123, 321; or 979, 799)

Comment: the jackpot would be 3 matches in the exact order but that would be easy to check for with a simple if statement (ex 123, 123; or 939, 939)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is what I think you will look for in your core code

```
public class Lottery{
    public boolean isWinner(ArrayList<?> user, ArrayList<?> lotto){

            if(user == null || lotto == null)
                return false;
            if(user.size() == 0 || lotto.size() == 0)
                return false;

            return lotto.containsAll(user);
        }
}
```

This uses ArrayLists of any type, and uses the existing containsAll() functionality.

This would be easy to setup

```
Lottery lottery = new Lottery();
ArrayList<Integer> userOne = new ArrayList<Integer>();
ArrayList<Integer> lotto = new ArrayList<Integer>();

userOne.add(/*Some int value*/); //do this XX number of times as needed
lotto.add(/*Some int value*/); //do this XX number of times as needed

lottery.isWinner(userOne, lotto);
```

**edit** This will work in the case of lotto={3,3,3} user={1,3,8} but breaks if you swap numbers: lotto={1,3,8}, user={3,3,3}. If you know the sizes will always be the same you can try

```
if(lotto.containsAll(user)){
    return user.containsAll(lotto);
}
return false;
```

Answer (score 2):

Well, to see if an array contains at least one element of another array, I'd do the following:

```
int[] actualNums;
int[] guesses;

for (int i = 0; i < actualNums.length; i++) {
    for (int j = 0; j < guesses.length; j++) {
        if (actualNums[i] == guesses[j]) {
            // if you are here, you have found at least one match.
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: yea that would help for checking for 1 match but then how would I know what index was matching if I had a repeating guess like 112 and the actual number was 123. It would tell me I have one match somewhere but I wouldn't know which index it was I'd still have to go through and check every possible outcome. What is the most efficient way to do that I'm wondering.

Comment: @Mateen, well, you can save the indices that you found the match at.  (If I find some time, I will update my answer)

Comment: yes that's what I need to do to make sure I don't compare repeating values. I would really appreciate it if you have any extra time :D

Answer (score 1):

If I were you, I'd use the `java.util.Random` class. In your case, you'd make it work like this. Start with importing the `Random` class.

```
import java.util.Random;
```

Then make an array of random integers 0-9.

```
int[] randomNums;
Random generator = new Random(); //instance of a Random object
for(int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
    randomNums[i] = generator.nextInt(10); //nextInt method gives int 0-9
}
```

For the user-inputted array, follow a similar process except using arguments. Then, you can iterate through the arrays together and see if they match. If you're doing what I think you're doing, you'd have to use nested `for` loops (two of them, to be precise).

Comment: Random generator = new Random();
Forgot "new".

Comment: I couldn't just use the Math.random() to generate random numbers and put them into an array?

Comment: From the JavaDoc -- public int nextInt(int n) : Returns a pseudorandom, uniformly distributed int value between 0 (inclusive) and the specified value (exclusive), drawn from this random number generator's sequence -- The code as written would return values from 0 to 8 and would not return 9. `generator.nextInt(10)` would return values between 0 and 9

Comment: My bad, stupid errors. Anyway, I think the Random class is more versatile

Answer (score 0):

You should put your numbers into a collection class like `List` (duplicates allowed) or `Set` (no duplicates here). Then you can use the existing methods `contains()` or `equals()` to look for matches.

Comment: Ooh, what is the limit for constant lookup of autoboxed primitive values?